# Session End Event

Tags: session, timeout

I am working in ASP.net 3.5 C#. What i am trying to do is when Session_End event gets called, I want to update the logged in User's status in database that the current User has logged out by any means (Logged out manually, Session time out etc. It calls Session_End Event). The problem is i am not bale to maintain the UserID. I can't access Session variable as session has already expired cookies also dint work for me.

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks a lot

Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing the UserID to ViewState, if you have a BasePage from which all your pages inherit or if you use MasterPage then it should be quite easy to push the UserID to viewstate on each page. Cookies should be alive beyond session life. Are you setting Expiry time to your cookie?

Comment: yes I am setting expiry time of 14 days.Also I am using master page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access session variables in Session_End event. All data stored in a session are deleted after the Session_End event finished. But you should be careful, because sessions are created for all visitors. If you store UserID in a session then it can be null inside Session_End if someone viewed the login page, but did not log in. It is not recommended to set the session timeout to days, because these sessions may fill all server memory.